# Ajax Auto populate php Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am bulding a simple php form to auto populate data on PHP form. I have checked other examples in this page [Auto fill form input fields from database using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516096/auto-fill-form-input-fields-from-database-using-ajax) which look same but i cant figure out my problem. I understand risk of sql injection on msql query but this is simple form

**my text boxes and auto populate script**

```
<style>
    form input { padding: 3px; }
</style>

<p><u><strong>Kindly enter the Trip ID to Generate a Budget.</u></strong></p>

<form align="center">
    Ref No:<br />
    <input name="refno" type="text" class="ed" /><br />
    Distance:<br />
    <input name="distance" type="text" id="distance" class="ed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /><br />
    Fuel Cost/Litre<br/>
    <input name="fuelcostperl" type="text" id="fuelcostperl" class="ed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /><br />
    <br><hr><table border=0 cellpadding=2>
        <tr><td>Req No:</label></td><td><input type='text' name='req_id' id="req_id" size=5 onchange="updateBudget()"></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=3>The following are details of the budget:</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Initials:</td><td><input type='text' id='init' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type='text' id='fname'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Othernames:</td><td><input type='text' id='Othernames'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email Address:</td><td><input type='text' id='email'/></td></tr>
        <td>Trip Date:</td><td><input type='text' id='tripdate'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Drop Date:</td><td><input type='text' id='dropdate'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Destination:</td><td><input type='text' id='destination'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Number Of Persons:</td><td><input type='text' id='no_persons'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Vote:</td><td><input type='text' id='vote'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Trip Purpose:</td><td><input type='text' id='tripreason'/></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script>
    var ajax = getHTTPObject();

    function getHTTPObject()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else {
            //alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function updateBudget()
    {
        if (ajax)
        {
            var reqValue = document.getElementById("req_id").value;
            if (reqValue)
            {
                var url = "populatebudget.php";
                var param = "?req_id=" + escape(reqValue);

                ajax.open("GET", url + param, true);
                ajax.onreadystatechange = handleAjax;
                ajax.send(null);
            }
        }
    }
    function handleAjax()
    {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4)
        {
            budgetarr = ajax.responseText.split(",");

            var init = document.getElementById('init');
            var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
            var othernames = document.getElementById('othernames');
            var email = document.getElementById('email');
            var tripdate = document.getElementById('tripdate');
            var dropdate = document.getElementById('dropdate');
            var destination = document.getElementById('destination');
            var no_persons = document.getElementById('no_persons');
            var vote = document.getElementById('vote');
            var tripreason = document.getElementById('tripreason');

            init.value = budgetarr[0];
            fname.value = budgetarr[1];
            othernames.value = budgetarr[2];
            email.value = budgetarr[3];
            tripdate.value = budgetarr[4];
            dropdate.value = budgetarr[5];
            destination.value = budgetarr[6];
            no_persons.value = budgetarr[7];
            vote.value = budgetarr[8];
            tripreason.value = budgetarr[9];

        }
    }
</script>

<tr align="center">

<a href="transmanager.php">Back to Main Page</a>

</tr></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**my PHP link to database**

```
<?php
//you'll have to replace your credentials here
$mysqldatabase = "kuvs";
$mysqluser = "root";
$mysqlpassword = "";

//connect to db
$DBCONN = mysql_connect("localhost", $mysqluser, $mysqlpassword);
if (!$DBCONN)
    die("Couldn't connect to MySQL Server.");
//perform lookup
$query = "SELECT init,fname,othernames,email,tripdate,dropdate,destination,no_persons,vote,tripreason FROM request WHERE req_id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['req_id']);
$result = mysql_db_query($mysqldatabase, $query) or die(mysql_error());

//print out results
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['init'] . "," . $row['fname'] . "," . $row['othernames'] . "," . $row['email'] . "," . $row['tripdate'] . "," . $row['dropdate'] . "," . $row['destination'] . "," . $row['no_persons'] . "," . $row['vote'] . "," . $row['tripreason'];
?>
```

My question is that I have been trying to populate all other fields but only first two are shown

Comment: Add `console.log(budgetarr);` after `budgetarr = ajax.responseText.split(",");` to see what response you are getting, if the response is not correct than check your php code otherwise debug your javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Venkat it was only mess up in the uppercase. I changed `Othernames` as `document.getElementById('othernames');` it worked. Is there any program or plugins that can correct this?
otherwise thank you for all who had opinions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mysql_fetch_array` use `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Please check `document.getElementById('othernames');` ID mentioned as wrong, in html code it was mentioned as `Othernames`. Javascript is case sensitive

Comment: mysql_fetch_array gives both based on index as well as based on table fields

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['init'].",".$row['fname'].",".$row['othernames'].",".$row['email'].",".$row['tripdate'].",".$row['dropdate'].",".$row['destination'].",".$row['no_persons'].",".$row['vote'].",".$row['tripreason'];
}
```